# URL pattern with multiple names

Tags: django, django-urls

Is it possible to define multiple [names](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns) for the one URL pattern? I'd like to merge two views without finding all the references to each and changing them. Another benefit in keeping both names is in case I ever want to split them again later.

For example, merging

```
url(r'^login/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='login.html'), name='login'),
url(r'^profile/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='profile.html'), name='profile'),
```

to

```
url(r'^profile/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='profile.html'), name=('login', 'profile')), #???
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it isn't possible to use a tuple for the url pattern's name. Just include the url pattern twice, with a different name each time.

```
url(r'^profile/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='profile.html'), name='login'),
url(r'^profile/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='profile.html'), name='profile'),
```

Note that I have terminated the regexes with a dollar. Without it, the regex will match `/profile/sonething-else/` as well as `/profile/`.